# Why my MVC views are compiled with PDB?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Now this is interesting!

I just noticed that exceptions in my MVC Views have line-numbers in the stack trace! Which means - my views are compiled with PDB.

I looked at the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder on my server - and **yes**, there are PDB files for every view.

**I have `<compilation debug="false"/>` in my web.config.**

**Why is this happening and how do I disable that?** This is the production server, so I would like to disable the pdb-generation.

I checked my "web.config", "Views/web.config", "machine.config", default "web.config" in `windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\` - I think I haven't found any suspicious compiler options there... Where do I look?

Or am I just wasting my time and this is the default option that cannot be changed?

PS. More info, just in case: this is an MVC 4 app, the Views are written in Razor.

Comment: I suspect it's just a default that you cannot change. When I compile any project (e.g. class library) in Release mode I still get pdb files generated.

Comment: I think if you use the Publish feature then it doesn't emit the PDBs and only includes the minimum necessary files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!!

Seems like this is the default setting for Razor - [it is always compiled with DEBUG option and you can't change it](http://forums.asp.net/t/1625220.aspx?Razor%20compilation) - but I think I found the solution.

Adding this to your machine.config seem to fix the issue:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <deployment retail="true"/>
    <system.web>
</configuration>
```

At least I don't see any more .pdb's in my "Temp ASP.NET Files".

More info about this flag on ScottGu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled